# Load hibernate entitiy into sub sub class

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following situation:

```
class Animal (holds all attributes, of course public getter+setter)
class Dog extends Animal (holds only specific methods)
class Cat extends Animal (holds only specific methods)
```

I want to store all animals in the animal table. But when I load them I want to say somehow in which subclass they are loaded. Animal is in this case theoretically abstract.

is something like this possible:

```
session.createCriteria( Animal.class ).addRestriction( .. ).mapTo( Cat.class ) ...
```

The problem is that otherwise I don't see any possibility to cast from the loaded Animal to Cat. :(

I'm using hibernate 4.2

Comment: Create the criteria on the correct subclass... Maybe read [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html).

Comment: I tried session.createCriteria( Cat.class ). ... but no query was fired (also no Exception). I just marked the Animal class with @Entity. Did I miss here something at subclass?

Comment: You are not telling Hibernate that you have an inheritance hierarchy so obviously it doesn't know what to do. If you are using JPA annotations [this should help](http://java.dzone.com/articles/jpa-implementation-patterns-mapping). You need to annotate _all_ classes with `@Entity` **and** specify the `@Inheritance` annotation on the parent.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21561696/how-can-one-override-a-method-from-a-hibernate-mappedsuperclass-but-keep-the-or/21561785

Comment: Thx .. the solution for my problem was to put the @Entity annotation to the animal as well as the sub classes. Hibernate does even store which sub class was stored so that I don't have to care about that. Very nice thx.

Answer (score 0):

Who don't you just select the Entity you want?

Cat is part of Animal

```
SELECT cat FROM Cat cat ...
```

will return the Cat Entity only, even if you habe a one table strategy.